# How to model a database where products have "n" presentations depending on "m" branches? Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, api, data-modeling

I have a issue when I try to model the database and return the data with laravel api resources.

The rules are:

- A product belongs to many branches and a branch can have many products. (Relationship many to many, here I have no problem)
- A product can have many presentations depending on the branch. (Here is my problem)
- Presentations are additional columns to the product such as quantity and price

For instance:

1. Product: Hamburger

   - Branch: Peru

     - Presentations:

       - small, 7 dollars
       - large, 15 dollars
   - Branch: Mexico

     - Presentations:

       - medium, 30 dollars
       - small, 10 dollars

What would modeling be like in the database?
And how should I display the data with Api laravel resources?

Thanks!

PD: I attach the Json code that must be returned.

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Hamburguer",
    "branches": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Peru",
            "presentations": [
                {
                    "quantity": "small",
                    "default_price": 7
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "large",
                    "default_price": 15
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Mexico",
            "presentations": [
                {
                    "quantity": "medium",
                    "default_price": 30
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "small",
                    "default_price": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Eloquent HasManyThrough](https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-has-many-through) relationship. How you return that data in your API is up to you, you can follow a spec such as JSONAPI, or define your own structure.

Comment: @Peppermintology When I use "through", it shows all presentations of the product. I want it to show only the available presentations of the product in a specific branch.